# migration error: Using the same entity twice

Tags: model-view-controller, ef-code-first, migration

Entities:

```
public class Match
{
    [Key]
    public int MatchId { get; set; }
    public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }
    public int AwayTeamId { get; set; }
    public string HomeTeamScore { get; set; }
    public string AwayTeamScore { get; set; }
    public string Stadium { get; set; }
    public string MatchDate { get; set; }
    public string MatchTime { get; set; }
    public string InsertDate { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HomeTeamId")]
    public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AwayTeamId")]
    public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Match> Matches { get; set; }
}

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<BalikciContext>
{

    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(BalikciContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

Error: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Matches_dbo.Teams_AwayTeamId' on table 'Matches' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

whats the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework won't be able to figure out where the Matches collection is pointing (Home or Away?). You need something like this for attributes (could also use fluent api):

```
public class Team
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("HomeTeamId")] 
    public virtual ICollection<Match> HomeMatches { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("AwayTeamId")] 
    public virtual ICollection<Match> AwayMatches { get; set; }
}
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Relationships